# run office-js taskpane from vba

Tags: office-js

is it possible to organise work with using VBA? 
     I have large VBA application which using external VB.API and want to use this legacy.
 1)  How to setup maninfest with using VBA ?
 2)  How to run  OfficeJS task pane application from VBA code?

Comment: Is there something specific you're doing in VBA today that cannot be done in Office.js instead?

Comment: Of course there is. To start with - call .net methods from other assembly. This could be achieved thru rest api workaround, but if that assembly has UI - simple winform, - you can invoke it thru vba, but cannot thru rest api.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no supported interaction between VBA/VSTO/COM and Office.js. They are very different technologies with entirely different architectures.

Comment: My question IS 

   is it possible to add OfficeJS button to Custom TaskPane (XLAM). It.s not pure VBA - it's just XML statement

Comment: If you're asking about adding an button to the Ribbon that triggers an Office.js add-in, this is not supported. The buttons in the ribbon are defined within the add-in's manifest. If you're asking if you can host an Office.js add-in within your own task pane, this is also not supported.